# How can I make a function creating tens of thousands of symbolic filesystem links show up in VTUNE?

Tags: c++, linux, centos7, intel-vtune

I'm profiling some binary on CENTOS 7.6 using VTUNE. I've yet to find the function (in vtune output) which is creating tens of thousands of symbolic file system links. And there is another one reading many such links, which I also cannot find. I used both,

- basic hotspot analysis
- locks and waits

Is the "basic hotspot analysis" only user-CPU-time but excludes system-CPU-time?

Where can one find the actually time spent (not CPU time) inside a function?

Comment: Are you interested only in the symlinks? I think you'd have an easier time with `strace -k`.

Comment: I'm using VTUNE in order to make my code faster.

Comment: Yes. I was suggesting a different, more suitable tool for this task. `strace -k` will tell you the stacktrace of every syscall your program makes.

Comment: strace is not a profiling tool. It will not tell me, if the system task in question is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Hotspot analysis includes **System-CPU** time too. To be clear, the total time (real CPU time) is the combination of the amount of time the CPU spends executing a program and the amount of time the CPU spends performing system calls for the kernel on the program’s behalf.

**Actual time spent inside a function**: After running hotspots analysis, hover to the bottom-up tab in Vtune GUI to view the execution time for all functions in the user code. Double click on any of the function to view the execution time

[image]